# Display a git branch in a subdirectory of heads in the bash prompt

Tags: bash, git

I can display my current git branch as long as it's not in a subfolder of heads, but when I go into a sprint/issue branch it no longer displays. I would like to be able to display these in addition to those in the root directory.

- This displays in bash correctly: `.git/refs/heads/dev`
- This does not: `.git/refs/heads/sprint1/12345`

Below is my current `.bashrc`.

```
parse_git_branch() {
   git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[1;36m\]\u\[\e[0;35m\]@\[\e[m\]\[\033[0;31m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "
```